# Speed up VIM cursor moving through j/k

Tags: vim, macvim

On my friend new Mac, he scrolls from line #1 to line #100 using `k` in around 4 seconds.
On my Mac, it takes 10 seconds. Neither of us know what causes his MacVim scrolls that fast.

Any way that I can improve the speed of scrolling on my MacVim? I already enabled `ttyfast` and `lazyredraw`

Comment: It shouldn't take you 4 seconds to scroll to line 100 ;-)

Comment: same file? same vim config? same plugin set?

Comment: same MacVim build? same OS version? same machine? same keyboard?

Comment: How long does it take to insert 100 `j` characters in insert mode; i.e. what is your keyboard repetition rate?

Comment: @IngoKarkat Around that amount of time: 10 seconds.

Comment: @Stefan: I agree. The point is not to jump to line 100 with k, but to know why his VIM is much more responsive to keyboard compare to mine.

Comment: @Kent + romainl: Not quite. He's on 10.9 and I'm on 10.8.5. We are both using the same version of MacVim build, and same default Janus settings.

Comment: @PhươngNguyễn first make the two vims with same vim conf, plugins-set, then try to open the same file in two vims. final advice, do NOT use Janus and other vim "distributions".

Comment: I began to use iterm2 at last.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The problem might be the difference in your keyboard settings instead of Vim. Try changing the Key Repeat setting in OS X' keyboard settings and see what happens. On my MacBook this setting affects the cursor movement speed when holding `h`, `j`, `k` or `l`.

As mentioned in comments some software such as KeyRemap4Macbook can override the system settings.

Also consider using commands `^U`, `^D` and `G` instead of `hjkl` when navigating around longer files.

[image: OS X keyboard settings]

Comment: I already set them to the max like being shown on your screenshot

Comment: Is one of you using KeyRemap4Macbook? That has its own key repetition settings that override the ones in the preference pane.

Comment: Omg, you are my hero man. KeyRemap4Macbook is overriding my keyboard repetition settings. Uninstall it and now my MacVim is as fast as my friend. Please make an answer then I'll accept it :)

Comment: @PhươngNguyễn if you want to get it even faster you can install the program Karabiner to set custom millisecond keyboard values for ```Delay Until Repeat``` and ```Key Repeat```, among many other things (be careful tinking too much with the abilities it gives you, though).

Comment: I just use `brew cask install karabiner` to install karabiner, then change the default setting for delay until repeat from 250 to 150, and the Repeat from 50 to 30. It's very easy to use, thanks